# Liferay Service Builder Error

Tags: java, eclipse, liferay, liferay-6

I was using the Service Builder in Liferay 6.2 CE but when I closed my project and opened it again, it was all messed up. I can run my project without a problem but I can't make changes to the Service Builder anymore...

When I open the service.xml file I get the following message:

[image: Liferay Service Builder Error]

I updated Eclipse and Sapphire but still the same.

Software Versions:

- Eclipse: Kepler Service Release 1
- Liferay IDE: 2.0.0.201312200205-ga1
- Sapphire: 0.7.0

**EDIT**

The contents of service.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE service-builder PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Service Builder 6.2.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-service-builder_6_2_0.dtd">
<service-builder package-path="com.nosester.portlet.eventlisting">
    <author>fvoordeckers</author>
    <namespace>Event</namespace>
    <entity local-service="true" name="Event">
        <column name="eventId" type="long" primary="true"></column>
        <column name="name" type="String"></column>
        <column name="description" type="String"></column>
        <column name="date" type="Date"></column>
        <column name="locationId" type="long"></column>
        <column name="companyId" type="long"></column>
        <column name="groupId" type="long"></column>
        <column name="userId" type="long"></column>
        <column name="createDate" type="Date"></column>
        <column name="modifiedDate" type="Date"></column>
        <order by="asc">
            <order-column name="date"></order-column>
        </order>
        <finder name="GroupId" return-type="Collection">
            <finder-column name="groupId"></finder-column>
        </finder>
    </entity>
    <entity name="Location" local-service="true">
        <column name="locationId" type="long" primary="true"></column>
        <column name="name" type="String"></column>
        <column name="description" type="String"></column>
        <column name="streetAddress" type="String"></column>
        <column name="city" type="String"></column>
        <column name="stateProvince" type="String"></column>
        <column name="country" type="String"></column>
        <column name="companyId" type="long"></column>
        <column name="groupId" type="long"></column>
        <column name="userId" type="long"></column>
        <column name="createDate" type="Date"></column>
        <column name="modifiedDate" type="Date"></column>
        <order by="asc">
            <order-column name="name"></order-column>
        </order>
        <finder name="GroupId" return-type="Collection">
            <finder-column name="groupId"></finder-column>
        </finder>
    </entity>
</service-builder>
```

Comment: do you have proper DB connection details? or it could be the specific Liferay plugin issue.

Comment: Can you open service.xml in a regular XML editor, not in a diagram, and see if it's valid xml or if you find something fishy in there?

Comment: I can open it with any other editor, and the XML is valid (no build errors), it seems to be something with the Liferay IDE...

Comment: That sounds fun. Can you post the `service.xml`? Can you open the the file with a simple text editor (right-click, open with..., Text editor).

Comment: @rlegendi: I added the contents of service.xml

Comment: @FrederikVoordeckers Hm, strange, my IDE has no problems with your definition (I use the Liferay plug-in v1.6.2.v201303111029). Haven't tried to generate it thoug.

Comment: @rlegendi have you closed the xml and eclipse as well? And restarted it after that?

Comment: @FrederikVoordeckers I reopened the XML file with the editor, haven't checked with restarting Eclipse though.

Comment: @rlegendi: I think that's the case, I didn't have problems until I restarted Eclipse.

Comment: I found that once I got that error, I couldn't get the service builder editor to work again unless I simplified the service.xml to the point that there were no entities containing the same column name. Yea, call it superstition, but try opening in the XML enditor, cutting the Location entity, saving, and seeing if you can open using the Service Builder editor.  If yes, then paste back in the Location entity and try that.  Besides occasional issues with my service.xml, I consistently cannot open the service.xml in Liferay Journal source.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be caused by the fact that the primary key of entity "Location" has the same name of a column of the entity "Event". If you want to keep the db column name as is, you may try to workaround the problem, giving "id" as a name to "Location" pk and setting db-name equals to "idLocation"